# SQL row count differently than array count which is defined at 10000. Please suggest. Expecting SQL row count should be same as 10000

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

```
if [ "${ARRAY_SIZE}" = "" ];then
  ARRAY_SIZE=10000
fi

declare
type t_reqseqArray is table of TEMP_TABLE_BKP.REQ_SEQ%type;
v_reqseqArray t_reqseqArray;
v_array_limit number(5) := ${ARRAY_SIZE};
v_commit_rate number(5) := ${COMMIT_RATE};
v_fetch_count number(5) := 0;
cursor c_reqseq is select req_seq from TEMP_TABLE_bkp;

v_TEMP_TABLE_bkp number(16) := 0;
v_array number(16) := 0;

begin
  open c_reqseq;
  loop
    v_fetch_count := v_fetch_count + 1;
        fetch c_reqseq bulk collect into v_reqseqArray limit v_array_limit;


        v_array := v_reqseqArray.count;
        dbms_output.put_line('Array count, '||to_char(v_array,'9999999')||' Request Sequences got');

        forall idx in 1..v_reqseqArray.count
         update TEMP_TABLE_bkp set req_seq=req_seq+1 where req_seq = v_reqseqArray(idx);
        v_TEMP_TABLE_bkp := sql%rowcount;

                exit when c_reqseq%notfound;
        if (v_fetch_count >= v_commit_rate) then
          dbms_output.put_line('Commit point reached, '||to_char(v_TEMP_TABLE_bkp,'9999999')||' Request Sequences got updated.');
          ${COMMIT};
          v_fetch_count := 0;
        end if;
  end loop;
  close c_reqseq;
end;
/
```

And result shows, Array count as 10000 where as SQL row count showed 12907.

Array count,    **10000** Request Sequences got
**12907**
Commit point reached,    **12907** Request Sequences got updated.
Array count,    **10000** Request Sequences got
**8660**
Commit point reached,     **8660** Request Sequences got updated.
Array count,     **4001** Request Sequences got
**2434**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sql%rowcount` is the number of rows updated by the whole `forall .. update` statement, not the number of times FORALL executed DML. Single update can affect many rows.

You can check also `SQL%BULK_ROWCOUNT` pseudo collection, it contains the number of rows affected for each DML statement executed by FORALL and you will see, that for some values v_reqseqArray(idx) it updated many rows.

Also bear in mind that your transaction sees your updates: cursor contains old values, the table contains updated, and UPDATE can see updates done in the same transaction.

BTW this is classic [fetch across commit](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:546822742166) example.